# Python BaseHTTPServer, how to redirect multiple hosts to ip/port?

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I currently have the following code:

```py
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from pathlib import Path
from random import randint

import json
import random

example = 'logs/example.json'

class GetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    # Slurp data from file
    def dummy_data(self):
        json_result = Path(example)

        if json_result.is_file():
            return json.load(open(example))

    # Return data or empty
    def random_selection(self):
        data = self.dummy_data()

        try:
            return random.sample(data, randint(1, len(data)+50))
        # Purposefully introduce entropy
        except ValueError:
            return ''

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

        self.wfile.write(json.dumps(self.random_selection()))
        return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from BaseHTTPServer import HTTPServer
    server = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8080), GetHandler)
    print 'Starting server at http://127.0.0.1:8080'


server.serve_forever()
```

I have patched `/etc/hosts` as follows:

```py
server-0001 server-0002 server-0003 server-0004 127.0.0.1
```

I am looking for a way for servers 0001-4 to redirect to `127.0.0.1:8080` but am not seeing how? Is this something to do with `/etc/resolv.conf`? I am using OSX but hopefully any *nix solution should work I'm hoping (unless ipfw evidently, since we no longer have it like sane people).

Comment: Take a look [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102663/87428). This is not a Python question.

Comment: @MauroBaraldi agreed but `/etc/hosts` does not handle port forwarding

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Perhaps [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/230300/what-is-the-modern-way-to-do-port-forwarding-on-el-capitan-forward-port-80-to) question may help you more :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the sanest answer was to patch `/etc/hosts`, then change port of `BaseHTTPServer` to `80`. This does not solve the origional question but is a fair compromise.

Patching Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# ensure running as root
if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ] ; then
  exec sudo "$0" "$@"
fi


if ! grep "^#- marker " /etc/hosts ; then
  echo -e '\n##+ marker' >> /etc/hosts
  while read server ; do
    [ 'x' != "${server}x" ] && echo -e "127.0.0.1 ${server}.io www.${server}.io" >> /etc/hosts
  done <read/servers.txt
  echo -e '\n##- marker' >> /etc/hosts
fi
```

Modification to Python

```
....
def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 80), GetHandler)
        print '->> Starting server at http://127.0.0.1:80 and all patched hosts'
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print '->> Interrupt received; closing server socket'
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```